# Blazor if condition change on button click

Tags: c#, html, blazor

I created a test project where I am working on dynamically changing the html content based on if, else if conditions. The entire functionality is in one razor page. Currently the html does not update on code change:

```
@page "/condition"

<h3>Condition</h3>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Number</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>First</td>
            <td>First</td>
        </tr>
        @if (second == true)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>Second</td>
                <td>Second</td>
            </tr>
        }
        else if(third == false)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>Third</td>
                <td>Third</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody> </table> <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@ChangeThird">Click me</button>


@code {
    bool second = true;
    bool third = true;

    private void ChangeThird()
    {
        third = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    } }
```

How do I make Blazor read the changes in the third property and display the new row ?

Comment: You are never setting `second` to false so that `if` will always be true.

Comment: So I have to use another independent if for the third row ?

Comment: No, you don't have to do that. I can't say for sure exactly what behavior you want, but you could toggle the values inside `ChangeThird()` like: `third = !third;` and `second = !second;`

Comment: You were on to something, I changed the else if condition into a separate if condition and the row is displayed after the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this:

```
else if(third == false)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>Third</td>
            <td>Third</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

to:

```
@if(third == false)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>Third</td>
                <td>Third</td>
            </tr>
        }
```

In short, remove: *else*

Incidentally, the StateHasChanged method is called automatically...

Hope this helps...